# Django postions: adding PositionField breaking migration

Tags: django, postgresql

I have already tables for Vehicle and Car, Using this [django-positions](https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions) for postioning my items of the tables. For that i have added the positon field in both the models.

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    position = PositionField()
```

And

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, related_name="vehicle")
    position = PositionField()
```

`makemigrations` ran fine but while `migrate` getting following error. using postgreSQL

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: check constraint "myapp_vehicle_position_check" is violated by some row
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that during the migration the SQL code checks for the value of the *PositionField* to be greater than or equal to 0. The default being **-1** for automatic ordering the migration fails.

I haven't digged any more but as a turnaround changing the default value to something equal or above zero allow for the migration to be successful.

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    position = PositionField(default=99)
```

Hope this helps.